# Can I use SQL Server-2012 Express edition over a network when the FIREWALL is on

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have enabled the TCP/IP, Named Pipe protocals and I have started the SQL Server web browser also. Still not able to connect to SQL Server2012 Express edition from some other system apart from my own system, where it is installed. Could please somebody tell me if i can connect to the express edition when Firewall is on. Also with SQL Server professional edition, is the network sharing is possible even when the firewall is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to make sure you're connecting through a known port, and open that port on your firewall.

In the configuration manager, open the TCP/IP settings. Under IPAll, ensure Dynamic Ports is blank and TCP Port is 1433. Then, make sure 1433 is allowed inbound on your firewall. If you have a network level firewall, check with it's administrators to make sure that port is open.

Yes, network sharing will work with the professional edition with a firewall - just need to make sure the correct ports are open.

Comment: Hi Matt, Thanks so much for the quick response. We have a network level firewall. I'll check with the administrator about the port open status.